# How to add image/icon for right side of a button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

These days I am developing flutter mobile application for the Android platform. I want to add a button with text an icon/image. That image must be the right side of the button text.

I have already attached the image here.

[image]

This is my code.

```
child: FlatButton.icon(
     icon: Image.asset("images/notesicon.png", width: 20.0,height: 20.0,),
     label: Text("Add Note",
        style: TextStyle(
           fontSize: 11.0,
           fontFamily: "Raleway"
        ),
     ),
     textColor: Colors.white,
     color: Color(0xFF226597),
     shape: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(
               style: BorderStyle.solid,
               width: 1.0,
               color: Colors.black),
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: so, show us what you tried so far

Comment: I used `FlatButton.icon`. but here that image comes to the right side only.

Comment: show text after icon: FlatButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.call),
                    label: Text(
                      'Call Me',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here you have your code fixed , don't use `FlatButton.icon` just use the `FlatButton` constructor and add a custom child , `Row` in this case.

```
    SizedBox(
            width: 150,
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Add Note",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, fontFamily: "Raleway"),
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    "images/notesicon.png",
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Color(0xFF226597),
              shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: When using `Row` as a `FlatButton`'s child, the button always tries to expand horizonally, which can be annoying. As per `FlatButton.icon` source code, you can use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` inside `Row` to prevent it from expanding.

Answer (score 58):

Just flip them. (lable<->icon) since they both accept any widget.

```
child: FlatButton.icon(
 icon: Text("Add Note",
    style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 11.0,
       fontFamily: "Raleway"
    ),
 ),
 label: Image.asset("images/notesicon.png", width: 20.0,height: 20.0,),
 textColor: Colors.white,
 color: Color(0xFF226597),
 shape: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(
           style: BorderStyle.solid,
           width: 1.0,
           color: Colors.black),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
  ),
),
```

Comment: Smart solution!

Comment: So clever solution!

Comment: Wow, thank you, swapping the direction of icon and text really works...

Comment: Upvoted for thinking outside the box!

Comment: This solution works, but note that the text may no longer wrap properly. (I was testing my app with a very large accessibility font size, and the text was truncated, rather than wrapping. Putting the text back in `label` made the text wrap properly again.)

Comment: good idea. good think, good approach.

Answer (score 8):

Try below code:

```
FlatButton(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   child: Row(
   children: < Widget > [
     Text("Make a Note"),
     Icon(Icons.note),
   ],
 ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
child: FlatButton.icon(
 icon:  Text("Add Note",
    style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 11.0,
       fontFamily: "Raleway"
    ),
 ),
 label: Image.asset("images/notesicon.png", width: 20.0,height: 20.0,),
 textColor: Colors.white,
 color: Color(0xFF226597),
 shape: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(
           style: BorderStyle.solid,
           width: 1.0,
           color: Colors.black),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
 Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 100,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue[400],
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue[800], width: 4.0),
                      borderRadius:
                      new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
                    ),
                    child:Center(child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => {},
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child:Center(child:  Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Make A Note"),
                          Icon(Icons.note_add),
                        ],
                      ),),),)),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget to create an independent button with action. and some necessary UI changes.

```
      Widget btnChooseFromDevice() {
        return Container(
          height: 56.0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                Text(
                  'Choose from Device',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Righteous',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                 Container(
                  width: 36,
                  height: 36,
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/file.png"),
                ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            onPressed: () {
              print('button pressed');
    //          getImage();
            },
          ),
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3.0)),
        ),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: FlatButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Add a Note"),
              Icon(
                Icons.note_add,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),[If you want Flatbutton like this you can use this following code][1]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your OutlinedButton.icon with a Directionality widget like this: This will make the icon to be at the right.

```
Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
  child: OutlinedButton.icon(
  onPressed: () {},
  
 label: Text(Testing),
 icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel,color:Colors.green,))),
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with text and icon on right side and custom size space between icon and text. Also added possibility to add border radius, border size and change padding.

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () => _myOnPressTestMethod(),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(child: Text("Test"),),
      SizedBox(width: 16),
      Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, size: 40,)
    ],
  ),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 10, bottom: 10),
    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
    side: BorderSide(width: 1.0,),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one out.

```dart
FlatButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLRTB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
        child: Row(
            children: < Widget > [
            Text("Add a Note"),
            Icon(Icons.note_add),
         ],
    ),
)
```